# Assistance with creating SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query that only returns rows with objects that have three or more orders in a week's timeframe and are only orders submitted after 9/1/13.

```
SELECT OrderID, DateSubmitted, ObjectID = i.ObjectID
FROM dbo.Object i
JOIN dbo.Order j
ON i.ObjectID = j.ObjectID
WHERE DateSubmitted >= '9/1/2013'
```

I just can't figure out how to narrow the results to those objects with three or more orders in a week. I've tried numerous `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please better define "three or more orders in a week's timeframe". Do you mean any 7 day period? Sunday to Saturday? Monday to Friday? This week? What if your start date was in the middle of a week?

Comment: @Joel, if I am not making it complex by my self then that means it is a sliding window calculation. something like see for given value n check if n, n+1 and n+2 is week range. For example for ObjectID-1 if the orderdates are 10/01, 10/03, 10/08, 10/09 then by looking at 10/01 next 2 date does not fall in Week range so 10/01 will not qualify. now looking at 10/03 next two values are withing Week Date range so thats why object-1 should be in the Result set.

Comment: So any seven days count as a week? So orders on 10/1, 10/2 and 10/7 would could as three in a week and for another objectID orders on 10/3, 10/4 and 10/9 would also count?

Comment: The week would be defined on a Monday - Sunday basis.

Comment: So the first week would be 9/2 - 9/8

Comment: ahhhh, so it is much simpler than I thought, it is a fixed week calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your last comments the query you looking for is very simple. use the DatePart function and find out WEEK of that object's order-date. check the below query. also unless you data base is configured already by default Sunday(int 7) is the First Day set in the SQL server. so you for this query purpose you need to set Monday(int 1) as the first day of Week.
you can check the current setting by executing  `SELECT @@DATEFIRST`

if same object has places 3 or more times for multiple weeks below query is returning that object for each of that week. if you needed only Objects then you can skip weekNumber from result set and do Distinct ObjectID.

**Do not forget to Reset the DATEFIRST setting to its original Value at the END.**

```
    DECLARE @Object TABLE
    (
        objectID        INT
    )
    DECLARE @Order TABLE
    (
        orderID         INT
        ,objectID       INT
        ,DateSubmitted  DATE    
    )

    INSERT INTO @Object( objectID )
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6

    INSERT INTO @Order ( orderID, objectID, DateSubmitted )
                SELECT 1,1,'10/2/2013'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 2,1,'10/3/2013'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 3,1,'10/5/2013'

    UNION ALL   SELECT 4,1,'10/09/2013'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 5,1,'10/10/2013'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 6,1,'10/13/2013'

    UNION ALL   SELECT 4,2,'10/15/2013'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 5,2,'10/16/2013'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 6,2,'10/21/2013'

    UNION ALL   SELECT 7,3,'09/02/2013'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 8,3,'09/03/2013'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 9,3,'09/04/2013'




    DECLARE @CurrentDateFirst INT=@@DATEFIRST
    SET DATEFIRST 1;
    SELECT i.objectID,DATEPART(week,DateSubmitted) AS weekNumber 
    FROM @Object i
    JOIN @Order j
    ON i.ObjectID = j.ObjectID
    WHERE DateSubmitted >= '9/1/2013'
    GROUP BY i.objectID,DATEPART(week,DateSubmitted)
    HAVING(COUNT(DISTINCT orderID) >= 3)
    ORDER BY i.objectID
    SET DATEFIRST @CurrentDateFirst
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT ObjectID 
FROM dbo.Object i
JOIN dbo.Order j ON  J.ObjectID = i.ObjectID
WHERE DateSubmitted >= '9/1/2013'
GROUP BY ObjectID 
HAVING COUNT(1) >=3
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure but i need more info on the tables 
best guess is in sql

```
SELECT count(OrderID), i.ObjectID
FROM dbo.Object i
JOIN dbo.Order j
ON i.ObjectID = j.ObjectID
group by i.ObjectID
having  DateSubmitted >= '9/1/2013' and count(OrderID)>2
```

Comment: does this check the DateSubmitted is within week range ?

Answer (score 0):

Convoluted, but I think this will get you what you want...

```
With    WeekSets As
(
        Select  i.ObjectID,
                j.DateSubmitted, 
                j2.OrderID
        From    dbo.Object i
        JOIN    dbo.Order j
                ON  i.ObjectID = j.ObjectID
        JOIN    dbo.Order j2
                On  j.DateSubmitted <= j2.DateSubmitted
                And j2.DateSubmitted < DateAdd(Day,7,j.DateSubmitted)
                And j.ObjectID = j2.ObjectID
        WHERE   j.DateSubmitted >= '9/1/2013'
),      GroupsOfThree As
(
        Select  ObjectID,
                DateSubmitted
        From    WeekSets
        Group   By  ObjectID,
                    DateSubmitted
        Having  Count(OrderID) >= 3
)
Select  Distinct j.OrderID, 
        j.DateSubmitted, 
        w.ObjectID
From    GroupsOfThree g
Join    WeekSets w
        On  g.ObjectID = w.ObjectID
        And g.DateSubmitted = w.DateSubmitted
Join    dbo.Order j
        On  w.ObjectID = j.ObjectID
        And w.OrderID = j.OrderID
```

Comment: The first CTE identifies OrderIDs within a week of eachother associated with an ObjectID. The second CTE looks at the week sets and determines which ones have at least three orders in the week timeframe. Finally the query uses the ad-hoc key from the second CTE to cull down our week sets to only the ones with three or more and then joins back to dbo.Order to get the Order details for those identified. The distinct is used to elminiate duplicates since order on 10/1, 10/2, 10/3 and 10/8 would have overlapping week ranges for both 10/2 and 10/3. 1,2,3 for one set 2,3,8 for the other.

Comment: @AnupShah I'm curious to hear what you think about this method for considering the week.

Comment: I haven't get time to check all use cases but it turn out that OP is way simpler than i was expecting. yet want to point out that good try if it covers rolling window.